# Ubuntu docker image is not running in the detached mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I created one image using below *Dockerfile*

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir -p /app   
COPY . /app         
CMD python /app/app.py
```

I am using this command to build the image:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t my-first-ubuntu-image .
```

And this one to run the container

```sh
Command for running the container : docker container run -d my-first-ubuntu-image
```

And when I run `docker ps -a*`, its status is showing `Exited`.
What is going on? I cannot understand because when I did the same for a `nginx` image, it is in `running` state.

Comment: Try running the container in the foreground (without the `-d` option); what does it say?  Does it exit immediately?  You can also use `docker logs` with the name or container ID from the `docker ps -a` output to see what it printed out.

Comment: @David when i run "docker container run -d ubuntu bash" it goes in exited state. have u ever face this.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what that command will do, generally with exit status 0.  In normal use you wouldn't run either an unmodified `ubuntu` container or `bash` as the main container command; the `docker run` command you show in the question is much more typical.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to prevent the container from dying:
`docker run -d my_image -d tail /dev/null -f`

The command `tail /dev/null -f` keeps the container busy forever.